# Webdriver Screenshot API does not take screenshot when machine is locked

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am facing issues with webdriver 2.3.x APIs.

```
1.Webdriver is not able to capture screenshots on IE when machine is locked. 
code I am using for screenshot is: 

File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)wd).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(<URL>));

2.Even, APIs like mouseover (using actions), click(), SwitchTo() does not work if machine gets locked while execution is in progress.
```

We are stuck because of the issues. Please do suggest a solution to overcome this problem.

Comment: Post the IE Driver server and IE browser version.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is how IE works. I suppose you don't have such a problem with FF/Chrome, do you?
This is not related to webdriver but browser itself. Check [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2964) for potential solutions.

Comment: Yes. I haven't encountered this issue with FF. The URLs mentioned do not talk about problems with the APIs not working. I scanned through the solution for screenshot however, did not found an answer to that to.

Comment: I wrongly assumed you use RDT. Anyway you can't let desktop to be locked. If you use PC to run test locally you need to switch off autolock. But I suggest to use VM instead.